# Android ACL_CONNECTED & DISCONNECTED firing up only once per app lifecycle

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, bluetooth, acl

I've currently run into a strange problem. I'm developing an app which needs to communicate with Bluetooth and I'm listening for Bluetooth changes as follows:

```
private fun createBluetoothIntentFilter() {
    var bluetoothFilter = IntentFilter()

    bluetoothFilter.addAction("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED")
    bluetoothFilter.addAction("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED")
    bluetoothFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)
    bluetoothFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)

    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, bluetoothFilter)
}

private var mReceiver = object: BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val action = intent!!.action

        if (action.equals("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED")) {
            Log.d("Z","Received: Bluetooth Connected");
        }

        if(action.equals("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED")){
            Log.d("Z","Received: Bluetooth Disconnected");
            isBluetoothConnected = false
        }

        // When the user turn the bluetooth on / off
        if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            val state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, -1)

            if (state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF) {
                isBluetoothConnected = false
            }
            else if (state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON) {
                isBluetoothConnected = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my manifest file I've included needed permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

The problem is that ACL_CONNECTED & DISCONNECTED are called only once per app lifecycle i.e. I open an app, here we get ACL_CONNECTED because the tablet is already paired with Bluetooth device, then I disconnect the Bluetooth device so the app will lose connection with BT device, the ACL_DISCONNECTED is fired up, then I'm connecting the device again, but neither ACL_CONNECTED or DISCONNECTEED is called any more on this app lifecycle.

I would also appreciate the clarification on when these ACLs are exactly called? Is it when socket.connect() happen? Because in android docs it's pretty hard to find.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
  protected val mReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
      val action: String? = intent.action
      when(action!!) {
        //STATUS_CONNECTING
        BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED -> {

          //TODO anything

          //for example
          val device: BluetoothDevice? =
                  intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
        }
        BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED -> {
          //TODO anything

          //for example
          val device: BluetoothDevice? =
                  intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
        }
      }
    }
  }

//then

bluetoothFilter = IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED)
this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, bluetoothFilter)

bluetoothFilter = IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED)
this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, bluetoothFilter)
```